# Vertex AI Pipeline is not using the GPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am building a customized pipeline with the following step:

```
     trainer_task = (trainer(download_task.output).set_cpu_request("16").set_memory_request("60G").
add_node_selector_constraint('cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator', "NVIDIA_TESLA_K80").set_gpu_limit(2))
```

However, when I check the number of GPU's available it says zero, and the only visible device is a CPU device. I am migrating a project from Kubeflow, and this is the first time using Vertex AI, so I am not pretty sure why this is happening.

The involved step is component that loads a docker image from the Artifact Registry and installs Tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1.

Am I missing something? Why is not enabling the specified GPUs?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The command itself is correct. I would check to ensure that the image you specified actually installs the CUDA drivers correctly. Maybe set up a vm with that image to test

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? I have a similar issue.